# Get all select values per div with multiple divs with same classname

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Is there a way to get an array of all the selected values inside a div with a particular class name when having more than one div with the same class name?

```
<div class="mydiv">
<select name="first">
     <option value="1">One</option>
     <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
<select name="second" ">
     <option value="1">One</option>
     <option value="2">Two</option>
</select> </div>

<div class="mydiv">
<select name="first">
     <option value="1">One</option>
     <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
<select name="second" ">
     <option value="1">One</option>
     <option value="2">Two</option>
</select> </div>
```

If i do this: `$(".mydiv").each(function (){ });`

I will be looping(twice in total as I have two divs with class mydiv) through both divs which is what I want. Now I would like to get the selected values in each div for each select(first and second).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/).

Following assumes you want a sub array for each `<div>`

```js
let res = $('.mydiv').map(function(){
    return [$(this).find('select').map(function(){
        return $(this).val()
    }).get()]
}).get()

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mydiv">
  <select name="first">
    <option value="1" selected>One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
  </select>
  <select name="second">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2"  selected>Two</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="mydiv">
  <select name="first">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2"  selected>Two</option>
  </select>
  <select name="second">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2"  selected>Two</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

For a flat array just do :

```
let res = $('.mydiv select').map(function(){
   return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thank you :)